# Why does JSF deliver JavaScript ressources with the file extension .jsf and GET parameter ln=js?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

For example:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="foo.js" />
```

becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/foo.js.jsf?ln=js"></script>
```

Note the `.jsf?ln=js` part.

Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think .jsf causes jsf servlet to take control on how which resource to download and hence allows library versioning.

See:
[What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)